# Failed to move uploaded file to online server in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload the file and send file as attachment and download the file has attachment the uploaded file as to be moved to the folder name temp. I have given the permission chmod. But the file is failing to move to uploaded folder.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sending Email </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
// Read POST request params into global vars
include_once "db.php";

$name1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name1']));
$subject1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['subject1']));
$email1=$_POST['email1'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['sess_user4']);
  $to = "checkformemail@gmail.com";
 $from=$_POST['email1'];
 $fileatt      = $_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'];
 $fileatt_type = $_FILES['fileatt']['type'];
 $fileatt_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileatt']['name']);
 $fileatt_size = $_FILES['fileatt']['size']; 
 $aa=filesize($fileatt);
$headers = "From: $from";
if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
  // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
$name1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name1']));
  $file = fopen($fileatt,'rw');
  $content = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
 chmod("temp/", 0777); 
fclose($file);
$message="Name:$name1\n\n
          Email:$email1\n
          Subject:$subject1\n
          Phone No:$phone";
  // Generate a boundary string
  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


  // Add the headers for a file attachment
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
              "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
              " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
             "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
             "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            stripslashes($message). "\n\n";

  // Base64 encode the file data
  $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

  // Add file attachment to the message
  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
              "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
              " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
              //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
              //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
              $content . "\n\n" .
              "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

}

// Send the message
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($ok) {
   echo "<script>window.open('display.php','_self')</script>";
} else {
  echo "<p>Mail could not be sent. Sorry!</p>";
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileatt"]["tmp_name"],'temp/'.basename($_FILES['fileatt']['name']));
$query = "INSERT INTO register (name,type,size,content,name1,email1,subject1,phone,username) VALUES ('$fileatt_name','$fileatt_type','$fileatt_size','$content','$name1','$email1','$subject1','$phone','$username')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chown could also be a good idea, `chown -R yourusername:www- data /path/to/folder`

Comment: So what _are_ the permissions of the folders involved?

Comment: I want to download the uploaded file and view the contents. I need read,write  permission to the uploaded file

Comment: You need _write_ permissions to upload a file.

Comment: after file is uploaded I need read,write permission. I need to move the uploaded file to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo $_FILES["fileatt"]["tmp_name"],'temp/'.basename($_FILES['fileatt']['name']));

And see if you get the path as expected.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: It should have been a comment but I need 50 rep points for that. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Maybe there is a reason for the 50 points rule. Just maybe. ;-)

Comment: It gives chmod permission denied

Comment: Then your user doesn't have the privileges.

Comment: How do I need to give the privileges. I have given it chmod("temp/", 0777);   this way

Comment: Try to log in to the server and do chmod on the folder instead. It's probably because your apache user doesn't have privelege to do it. And maybe change the owner of the folder with chown.

Comment: Please never use 777, you should yse 775 and chown the folder to user:www-data, else everyone has permissions in the folder

Comment: I have tried with  775 permission also.It shows permission denied. Whether chmod command which I used Is correct chmod("temp/", 0775);. how do I use chown command?

Comment: sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data /path/to/folder/

Comment: chown("www data/xyz.co.in/r1/temp/$file","abc"); is this correct?

Comment: Is this on a linux system? If yes - Log in to the machine - chown -R user:group "path/to/folder/" . Ex. chown -R apache:apache data/xyz.co.in/r1/temp/

Comment: ohhh, i see, you're getting the errors because you're sending those commands through PHP, you should use these commands using the terminal. chmod won't work because PHP doesn't have permissions yet. so it cannot change the owners/permissions, do you have a SSH connection available to your server?